# How can I force drop a broken Postgres database?

Tags: postgresql

I have a database that seems to be broken for some reason. It's a development db for rails so I don't have a backup but I do need to continue development. I tried to just drop it but that's not working.

```
$ dropdb "database-name"
dropdb: database removal failed: ERROR:  could not open file "global/2964": No such file or directory
```

Thanks in advance for any help!

Comment: try rake development db:drop

Comment: `rake development db:drop` is not a rails rake task.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's more wrong here than a "broken" database. Something is badly wrong with your PostgreSQL data directory.

`global/9264` looks like it's `pg_catalog.pg_db_role_setting`, which stores `ALTER DATABASE ... SET ...` and `ALTER ROLE ... SET ...` settings. This is not database-specific, it's a global table.

If you have missing files in your data directory your whole PostgreSQL data directory is probably damaged. You should back up what you can, if there's anything you care about, then rename or delete the damaged data directory and `initdb` a new blank one.

You won't be able to `DROP` this database (or do much else) because PostgreSQL can't load the files for the `pg_db_role_setting` table, but it needs to delete entries referring to the dropped database from there.

---

As for how this happened:

- Have you ever run with `fsync = off` in `postgresql.conf`?
- Do you have SSD storage? If so, have you had any recent sudden power loss?
- Have you ever done any direct modifications of any kind inside the PostgreSQL data directory?
- Is the PostgreSQL data directory on external storage that might have been suddenly removed?
- Have you ever deleted `postmaster.pid` ?

See also https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Corruption

Comment: OK, yes I do use SSD storage and sometimes my computer freezes so that might explain the corruption. I moved the database files from `/var/lib/postgres/data` to `data.old` and tried to init but got no permission so I did `chown postgres:postgres /var/lib/postgres` and was able to then init. However, I am still getting the same error. I think maybe my database is in a different place.

Comment: It turns out I had to restart the background service with `sudo systemctl restart postgresql` after removing the old files and doing an init. Thank you for your help!

Comment: You should really stop PostgreSQL, delete/rename, init, then start it again. Don't leave it running while deleting all its files, you don't want the old postmaster to try to write into the newly initdb'd directory. Also, if you have freeze/crash issues and an SSD, make sure it's a decent quality SSD with supercapacitor or other power loss protection. Or keep good backups.

Comment: OK, that makes sense. Thank you!